# Was T-Bob inspired by astromech droids or something else?

Tags: cartoon, inspiration, toys, mobile-armored-strike-kommand

One of the characters I remember most from M.A.S.K was [T-Bob](https://mask.fandom.com/wiki/T-Bob) who always reminded me of R2D2.

[image: T-Bob who looks like an egg with arms]

The page on fandom states that Wikipedia *used* to have a whole page for the character making the connection, but as T-Bob now redirects to the [List of Characters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_M.A.S.K._toys_%26_characters) page instead.

The writers of the show were probably aware of other robots in fiction given T-Bob makes a possible reference to Marvin from Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy:

> "M.A.S.K.? No, I don't know anyone named Mask. I used to know somebody named Marvin but he doesn't live around here."
> - "The Deathstone"

The fandom page also lists other possible connections, but nothing from the toy or TV show creators.

Is there a statement explaining what if anything inspired T-Bob out-of-universe?

Comment: [*"For T-BOB there was already a rough round design before I joined the project, so I transformed it into a one-wheeled bike that kids could ride."*](https://kenner-mask.com/publisher.item.82/Interview-with-mechanical-designer-Shinji-Aramaki.html?keywords=t-bob)